# Как выбрать поле из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть запрос к БД:

```
public function getCategoryNames($product_id) {     
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT *
    FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd
    LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (p2c.category_id = cd.category_id)
    WHERE p2c.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");     
    return $query->rows;
}
```

Как выбрать поле top из таблицы **oc_de_av_category**?
[Скриншот](http://prntscr.com/h6uq6c)

Знаю, что за это отвечает **LEFT JOIN**, но самому не получается составить запрос.

Comment: по какому полю связана oc_de_av_category с другими таблицами?

Comment: по category_id связана

Comment: Вам нужно добавить еще один join LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "oc_de_av_category oc ON (cd.category_id = oc.category_id)

Comment: но важно правильно соединить таблицы. не видя структуры, сложно сказать, какую именно нужно джойнить. судя по названию таблиц - category_description и oc_de_av_category

Comment: решение тут https://toster.ru/q/476756

Comment: решение правильное, но будьте внимательны - те ли таблицы соединяются